# jq filter on array and return matching elements with full array name

Tags: jq

i have below JSON which i am trying to filter using `"isEnabled"` value. I am able to filter  but loosing original array as result only shows filtered data. is there any way to return result in same array?

```json
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "pageSize": 200,
  "totalCount": 174,
  "resultSize": 174,
  "sortType": "asc",
  "sortBy": "policyId",
  "queryTimeMS": 1697604282484,
  "policies": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "guid": "d3a007c9-a877-44b8-a526-57f484916cd6",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "version": 210,
      "service": "Prod-Hue",
      "name": "all - url",
```

My JQ line

```bash
cat myjson.json | jq '.policies[] | select(.isEnabled == false)'
```

also tried enclosing entire jq expression in () but no joy.

Comment: What if you replace `|` operator(just before `select` ) with `|=` ?

Comment: Don't change the context with `|`. Use update `|=` instead. (And provide the input file as parameter): `jq '.policies[] |= select(.isEnabled == false)' myjson.json`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

[pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) suggested change (see comments):

```bash
cat myjson.json | jq '.policies = [.policies[] | select(.isEnabled == false)]'
```

**Previous Response**

This should keep the whole structure of the JSON but filter out policies (depending on `isEnabled == false`) in place.

```bash
cat myjson.json | jq '.policies = (.policies[] | select(.isEnabled == false) | . )'
```

Explanation:

1. `(.policies[] | select(.isEnabled == false)` -> Take each policy and filter out the results on the given condition.
2. `| . )` -> aggregate the results
3. `.policies = ()` -> reassign the field with the newly filtered array

Comment: Thanks for this input. this has worked like a charm.

Comment: With `.policies = (.policies[] | …)` you are duplicating the outer object (which contains `.policies`) as many times as there are results produced by `select`. It does **not** preserve the array. For that, you would need brackets instead of parens, to have an array to collect into, i.e. `.policies = [.policies[] | …]`. And get rid of the useless `| .`, it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: `|.` doesn't do anything, it can be removed